# SafeArea in iOS 11: how add view on main screen with custom navigationBar without safeArea from code in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode9

In my project on `Objective-C` mainScreen with Custom `NavigationBar` (created from code):

```
mainNavigationController = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainMenuViewController];
mainNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
mainNavigationController.delegate = self;
mainNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIWindow* window = self.window;
window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
window.rootViewController = mainNavigationController;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I change self.view like size [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame]:

```
UIView* mainView = [[[MainViewControllerView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame] autorelease];
self.view = mainView;
```

In mainScreenView I add scrollView:

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
scrollView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

And add some subView inside scrollView:

```
[scrollView addSubview:myLogoView];
[scrollView addSubview:littleScrollView];
[scrollView addSubview:firstButton];
[scrollView addSubview:secondButton];
[scrollView addSubview:thirdButton];
[scrollView addSubview:fouthButton];
[scrollView addSubview:fifthButton];
[scrollView addSubview:sixthButton];
[scrollView addSubview:seventhButton];
[scrollView addSubview:activityIndicatorView];
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ttrkolgnch80kr9/safeArea.png?dl=0

If use XCODE 8 and iOS <= 10, all view place correct on mainScreen (myLogoView place ignore size of custom NavigationBar and have coordinate Y == 20.0 in absolute value coordinates of device screen),
but if use `XCode` 9 and `iOS` 11 myLogoView have place under my custom navigationBar (height == 44) myLogoView Y == 64.0 in absolute value coordinates of device screen, in iOS 10 (under xCode9) all working good - added view on mainScreen placed in start coordinates of screen and ignore height of custom `NavigationBar`.

In swift and storyboard I know how it fixed in iOS11 easy remove safeArea top line, but how remove safeArea **from code** in `Objective-C`.

How fix this trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Safe area in iOS 11 is replacement of top & bottom layout and apple provide more detail on this like below :

> The layout guide representing the portion of your view that is
>   unobscured by bars and other content. In iOS 11, Apple is deprecating
>   the top and bottom layout guides and replacing them with a single safe
>   area layout guide.

So base on this now top & bottom layout replaced with single **safe area** but agin if you are not using default NavigationBar so you can disable safe area in storyboard like below :

[image]

You can Uncheck safe area and it will revert to top & bottom layout.

Ref Before & After uncheck safe area:

**Before or default  :**

[image]

**Uncheck Safe area or old behavior :**

[image]

Hope this will help to understand new iOS 11 update related to top & bottom layout and change your code as per this layout change.

Also here is one good blog to explain more on Safe area layout : [Safe area](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/safe-area-layout-guide/)

Comment: Sorry, but the issue I mentioned know how to do it from storyBoard and Swift. Interested in is Objective-c

Comment: but if u disable safe area from storyboard it will solve ur problem b'cus as u mention safe area is creating problem for your custom Navigation bar so I don't think so after disable this not required to change any thing as its same as iOS 10.

Comment: in my project there is no storyboard and I can't disable this safe area from setting panel...

Comment: Ok so can you post your custom navigation bar code here so I can get idea whats wrong with that layout ? also pls share screen shot how its looks in iOS 11 with safe area.

Comment: <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/ttrkolgnch80kr9/safeArea.png?dl=0" width="200" height="100">

Comment: you check this thread for setting safeAreaLayout https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit/issues/448

Comment: Thanks, but these references are examples given only to the Swift code, my project in objective-c.... :(